# Searching and limiting to specific file types VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently searching a large solution to find the word *'reinsurance'*. I want to limit this to .cpp files only, excluding header files.

How can I go about this in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open "Find in Files" dialog by going Main Manu → Edit → Find and Replace → Find in Files, set file mask to `*.cpp;` or whatever.